# Why my managed process is terminated if a called unmanaged routine joins a thread it spawns?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, interop

C++ Code:

```
void callFromThread()
{
    printf("Some Text");
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()
    {
        printf("Hello from DLL !\n");

        std::thread first(callFromThread);
        //first.join();

        printf("Test Test");
    }
}
```

C# Code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
    public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DisplayHelloFromDLL();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If `first.join()` is commented up, my program terminates just after the unmanaged code is finished.

Could you please explain, why C# process is terminated?

Comment: Probably because some error in the C++ code crashed the process. Are both messages displayed? If you write a C++ `main()` that executes the `DisplayHelloFromDLL`, does it crash? If you wrap the `DisplayHelloFromDLL` call in a `try ... catch`, can you catch an exception?

Comment: Do you mean that it crashes when the call to `join` _is_ commented out, or when it _isn't_.  It would be perfectly normal for the program to crash if `join` is commented out.  You _must_ call either `join` or `detach` before a `std::thread` goes out of scope, or `std::terminate` will be called by the thread's destructor.

Comment: I found the reason, it is because of exception in thread destructor: 

 ~thread() _NOEXCEPT
  { // clean up
  if (joinable())
   _STD terminate();
  }
  
When join is commented out,
but how could I sort this out?

Comment: Like I said, you _must_ call either [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) or [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) before the thread goes out of scope or your process will be terminated.